# Delphi Chromium flash player

Tags: delphi, chromium

Estou montando um simples browser com o Chromium, porém quando abro um site em flash ele pede para instalar o plugin do flash, queria saber se existe alguma forma de carregar o flash para não precisar instalar no computador, ter alguma dll não sei...
Alguém sabe como ?

[componente de Chromium](https://delphimaniaco.wordpress.com/2016/03/15/utilizando-o-navegador-chrome-no-delphi/)

Comment: Você sabe afirmar com certeza se o Chromium não utiliza a api do IE ?

Comment: Não sei, mas resolvi da seguinte maneira:
>

program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  ceflib,
  cefvcl,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

procedure CustomCommandLine (const processType: ustring; const commandLine: ICefCommandLine);
begin
    commandLine.AppendSwitch('--enable-system-flash');
end;

begin
    CefCache := 'cache';
    CefOnBeforeCommandLineProcessing := CustomCommandLine;
    CefSingleProcess := False;
       if not CefLoadLibDefault then Exit;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end..

Comment: @RobinhodeMorais poderia criar uma resposta com esse código e uma breve explicação do pq funciona. Esse 'campo menor' é chamado de comentário e serve para pedir esclarecimentos.